# Using Block in Handler - Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am writing a handler for an Ansible role to stop and start Docker. The stop is written as follows in handlers/main.yml

```
- name: stop docker
  block:
    - name: stop docker (Debian based)
      block:
        - name: stop service docker on debian, if running
          systemd: name=docker state=stopped
        - name: stop service docker.socket on debian, if running
          systemd: name=docker.socket state=stopped
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr == "apt"
  
    - name: stop docker (CentOS based)
      block:
        - name: stop service docker on CentOS, if running
          service:
            name: docker
            state: stopped
        - name: stop service docker.socket on CentOS, if running
          service:
            name: docker
            state: stopped
      when: ansible_pkg_mgr == "yum"
```

Then in my tasks/main file, I'm calling stop docker

```
---
- name: test
  command: echo "Stopping docker" 
  notify:
    - stop docker
```

The error I'm receiving is `ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: 'Block' object has no attribute 'notified_hosts'`

If I run this as a task in a playbook it works.

Is there a way to use `block` in an Ansible handler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According your error message it seems that Ansible do not provide [`block`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) functionality for [`handlers`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html).

Instead you could use an other approach

```yaml
handlers:
  - name: Stop Docker
    include_tasks: tasks/stop_docker.yaml
```

and put the logic into a separate task file.

**Further Information**

- [Ansible Issue #14270](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14270)
- [Ansible Issue #20493](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20493)
- [Ansible Issue #42353](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/42353)
- [What's the difference between `include_tasks` and `import_tasks`?](https://serverfault.com/a/875292/448950)

Answer (score 3):

For me, neither `block` and  `import_tasks` did work (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html).

```
- name: do something else in somewhere else:
  include_tasks: roles/jh_load_services/tasks/main.yml
```

If that can help

Comment: I can confim: `import_tasks` did not work for me but `include_tasks` did. Ansible version 2.12.4.

Comment: For more info, see handler limitations: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#limitations

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar situation that I've resolved with the "listen" param in every single task within the block in handlers file.

```
- name: "restart server - Block"
  block:
    - name: "Ensure the webserver service is running with daemon-reloaded"
      systemd:
        name: webserver.service
        enabled: true
        state: restarted
        daemon_reload: true
      listen: "Restart Server"

    - name: "Wait until webserver is up and running"
      uri:
        url: 'http://localhost:8080'
        return_content: true
        validate_certs: false
        status_code: [200, 403]
      register: uri_output
      until: uri_output.status in [200, 403]
      retries: 12
      delay: 20  # seconds
    listen: "Restart Server"
```

and in the tasks file adding the notify param:

```
- name: "Install systemd webserver service"
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: webserver_service.j2
    dest: /etc/systemd/system/webserver.service
    mode: 0644
  notify: "Restart Server"
```

The trick works because you can have repeated listen params but having different task names. To be more conscious about the tasks are related you can have them in a block, but it's not necessary.

I've taken this idea from: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/77461#issuecomment-1088274545